# Not able to parse my json data coming from backend flask route file to show it in front end

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, python-3.x, flask

I have a python dictionary in my flask route file where it is converted in json. but when i fetch the file in front end file it shows that data is recieved but when i do data parsing. It shows invalid Json instead my backend has already made a Json string.

This is my front end fetch file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aYSr.png)

This is mt backend flask route file. Where json is already made.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6gjp.png)

After fetch call to recieve data from backend this msg comes in  front end
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW9eU.png)

I tried to parse the data using json.parse(data);
but it is not working.

Comment: Please don't ever post anything WITH ALL CAPS. And don't post pictures of code or other text.

Answer (score 0):

Because some responses are coming from your Flask server, it appears that the problem is with JSON parsing on the client side. I believe there is an error in the way you are parsing the JSON.

```
fetch("<top-level_domain>/beamd_cal").then(data => data.json()).then(data)=> {
   console.log("Data from the server: ", data)
}
```

Comment: supportrxn = beamd(bl,ns,nl,supportloc,supporttype,supportdirec,loadloc,loadtype,loaddirec,loadvalue)

  #print("supportrxn: ",supportrxn)
  list1 = ['R1', 'R2']
  result = dict(zip(list1,supportrxn))
  #print(result)
  d = json.dumps(result, indent=2)
  print("d data type: ",type(d))
  print(d)
  return d
 return render_template('beamdesign_cal.html')                                                                              This is how i am making JSON in backend. Is this correct as i have tried using jsonify also but didnt worked

Comment: so what to do now?